# how to call web api when are windows application installing time?

Tags: c#, installation, desktop-application, setuptools, webapi

I have developed windows application, and when the user tries to install at that time, call a web api and check if the user is an activated or registered user. again returned value wise install our windows application other wise rollback.

How can I do this functionality?

I already tried to follow this function in the installer class but it did not call the web api.

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("Search/Verifysystemreg",
new IdentityHelper
{
IdentityKey = IdentityKey,
Systemname = Systemname
});

Comment: Are you sure your client.PostAsJsonAsync() method works correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yes I checked it project. Where I call in Application form_load method its working correctly. but I want call a client.PostAsJsonAsync() from Installer class.

Comment: I put it installer class did not connect a server.  this is correct flow or not. if not then how to check my installation validation from server? Please guide me.

Comment: In which function did you write this api? can you share the code sample.